# how does the ignore parameter works in gulp and nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I'm trying to create a gulpfile that lint my personal javascript files (.js) but ignore any vendor/third party libaries.

My gulp file is listed below:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    jshint = require("gulp-jshint"),
    jasmine = require("gulp-jasmine"),
    nodemon = require("gulp-nodemon");


// lint JS files for bad habbits
gulp.task("lint", function () {
    gulp.src(["**/*.js", "node_modules/*"])
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter("default"));
});


gulp.task("nodemon", function () {
    nodemon({
            script: "server.js", 
            ext: "html css jade js", 
            ignore: ["node_modules/*"]
        })
        .on("change", ["lint"])
        .on("restart", function () {
            console.log("Change detected, restarting server ...");
        });
});

gulp.task("default",["nodemon"]);
```

When I run the **"gulp default"** command in my terminal it still lint the javascript files in the **node_modules**. I've tried variations of the glob syntax but I can't seem to achieve the desired behaviour.

Any idea where I've gone wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glob pattern you've set, `node_modules/*` only matches the files in the root of the `node_modules` directory, but not all the children with an highter depth.
You need to set is as `node_modules/**/*`, this will match everything. I advice you however to only match `js` files, with `node_modules/**/*.js`.

You also need to negate the pattern with `!`, *gulp* does not know that you want to do that, so it will look like:

```
gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**/*.js'])
```

For *nodemon*, following the same thing you can use the `node_modules/**/*` pattern.

The library used by gulp for globbing is minimatch.

Comment: Your line doesn't seem to work, gulp.src(['\*\**/\*.js', '!node_modules/*/\*\*.js']) but this one does gulp.src(['*/\*\*.js', '!node_modules/*/**.js']), notice the use of the asterisk for the first parameter. I can't seem to understand why, I'll look into miniwatch because I want to understand how glob patterns work rather than blindly fixing it. Thanks though.

Comment: Oh my bad, too quick, it was indeed the opposite `!node_modules/**/*.js`, will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

use this `ignore: ["node_modules/"]` without '*' and it will work